# Can anybody read running encrypted dvi disk without password?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, encryption, bitlocker, vdi

I have a question about privacy.
I have created the vdi disk via VirtualBox, install Windows 10 on it and turn on BitLocker.

Can anyone get access to the files on this disk without my password (from my host-computer)? I understand that it's entire disk encryption, but does any chance exist?

And if answer is no, than can anybody get access to my files on the disk during the virtual machine are running?
By another words, I mount disk, start VM, enter valid password and am working on it. Can anybody get access (from the network for example, vdi file is shared, it's possible) to the my running disk without password?

EDIT. Ok, my main question is: can anyone read encrypted before, but running now vdi disk? And how easy is it?

Comment: You cannot read encrypted data unless you decrypt it.  Your question does not make a great deal of sense for that reason.

Comment: I am interested in second question.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask in your second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you look at your virtual machine just as you look at a physical machine. Access to your vdi file is (practically) equal to access to a physical harddisk.

With that in mind:

- Access to a Bitlocked vdi file without Bitlocker password is not possible (unless the Bitlock encryption is broken).
- If you are running your virtual PC, no one can access your files **unless** you share a directory or a drive (don't forget about the *[administrative shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share)* (`$C`, etc.) that Windows or your virtual machine creates for you. In other words: securing your virtual PC is just as easy (or just as difficult) as securing your physical PC.

Ps: note that on the Information Security stack I would have said: everyone had access to your files, unless you prevent them to have access to those files. But here on Super User I'd like to look at it the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear enough to understand how vdi drive work. One more question: if I enter password, than I decrypt entire disk and ALL files unless I turn off VM? Or maybe BitLocker has some smart algorithm to decrypt files just-in-time?

Comment: The latter. Bitlocker adds an extra layer between the OS and the files on your harddisk. The entire disk is encrypted (which takes some time) and at the moment files are accessed by the OS, they are decrypted. Otherwise, it would take a very long time to start up your computer... ;-)